# .htaccess question - URL-rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an issue with URL-rewriting in .htaccess. Here is .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /community/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^view-all-results$ forums/index.php?view=view-all-results [R=302]
RewriteRule ^view-all-results/$ forums/index.php?view=view-all-results [R=302]
```

I need to rewrite url like "`/community/view-all-results?u=2`" to "`community/forums/index.php?view=view-all-results&u=2`".
But according to the above rule I'll get "`community/forums/index.php?view=view-all-results`".

I tried to change RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^view-all-results?(.*)$ forums/index.php?view=view-all-results&$1 [R=302]
```

But it doesn't work properly. It still rewrites URL to "`community/forums/index.php?view=view-all-results`".

When I changed rule(put + instead of *):

```
RewriteRule ^view-all-results?(.+)$ forums/index.php?view=view-all-results&$1 [R=302]
```

I've got URL like "`community/forums/index.php?view=view-all-results&s`". So I don't understand this behavior.((

I will be very appreciated for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic flag is [in the docs: `[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), which will add the original querystring to your url.

Normal matching is only done against the path, not agains the querysting, which you would find in the magic variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`).  Matching this variable can be done in a `RewriteCond` condition. You could also append this variable to the resulting url, but `QSA` is infinitely more userfriendely here.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /community/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^view-all-results/?$ forums/index.php?view=view-all-results [QSA]
```

Basically the first half of a RewriteRule doesn't match against the QUERY_STRING, so you second to example will never match against it. The main thing your first code was missing was the QSA flag, which tells it to pass the QUERY_STRING it receives along with the newly created QUERY_STRING. I also removed the R=302, as I assume you don't want the URL to change.

Edit: Oh, I also combined the rules by making the trailing slash optional.